# How do I print the stdout buffer size in Tcl?

Tags: tcl, buffer, stdout, channel

I have looked around, but couldn't find anything I might use to print the current buffer size of a channel (say `stdout`) in tcl.

I am planning on using `fconfigure` to readjust the buffer size, but I'd like to know what the current size is, before I change it, as a benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply omit the actual buffer size argument.

```
set bufferSize [fconfigure stdout -buffersize]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
% fconfigure stdout
-blocking 1 -buffering none -buffersize 4096 -encoding utf-8 -eofchar {} -translation lf
%
```